# Python script to launch Energy Plus with command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, subprocess, launch

> Solved

I need to run a huge number of simulations using a software: Energy Plus.
I want to create a Python script in which I make these call to process.
Energy Plus takes 2 input files, I have alredy set the 2 files I want Energy Plus to take as default, so every time I make a call, the software opens it is ready to start without modifing inputs. But I don't know how to make Energy Plus run after that I call the process.
At the moment these are the 2 strings of code:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call(['C:\EnergyPlusV8-8-0\EP-Launch.exe'])
```

[This image show the situation after the call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etS7H.png)
I want to find a way to run Energy Plus after the call, without the necessity to "push" the button `"Simulate.."` .

Comment: Your questions is not about launching - you solved that. Your question is about automating a app by finding its window, find the button and click it .... unless your software has a commandline switch to start the simulation at once which would make it far easier.... did you google/try  this: https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/blob/develop/doc/running-energyplus-from-command-line.md  and checked if its start is scriptable?

Comment: Thank you a lot for you help. I'm trying the to use those commands. But do you know how then I can integrete it directly in the python scripts. Becaus eI still need it, since I want to perfome some operations on input file, before to launch it again and so on.

Comment: If none of the input parameters linked in last comment automatically start the simulation ( == press the button for you) you need someone able to help you automating this button press. If you need to modify the EL files before starting it you can do that with python, Clarify what you need in your question and adapt the title ("Python started app, window pops up, need to automate button click in this window") after searching SO and google for similar questions and try the solutions presented there. If you need to modify the input files with pythong, SO provides lots of answers on how to

Comment: read text files, parse them, write them back.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickArtner . I will update the title after that read more about what you told. Currently i have alredy made 2 classes to work on my files. One in which I decide what to change in my input file and another one in which I update the information on the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my iusses.

Check this link, they explain in details different solutions "[Specifically about the problem I had](https://unmethours.com/question/22157/run-energyplus-from-python/)"
Furthermore, an interesting idea to solve any doubt [Python class for EnergyPlus](https://github.com/jamiebull1/eplus_worker/blob/master/worker/runner.py)